# Is it normal to read a connection between pins 2 and 4 of a GPIO breakout board?

Tags: gpio, hardware, power, electronics, breadboard

So, I recently bought [this cobbler kit](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1105) from adafruit, and finished up the soldering as they instructed.
However, after doing so, I hooked the cobbler up to my breadboard to test the connections.
I noticed that between pins 2 and 4, there was low resistance, whereas between other pins there was no connection.

I'm wondering, is this normal? On the board, the pins both are labelled "5VO",
but in "Rapsberry Pi User Guide" 2 is labelled "5V0" and 4 is "DNC".
Either way, I don't want to fry my pi by short-circuiting the 5V output.

Do I need to resolder my board, or is this normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Pin 2 and Pin 4 produce 5V so this is expected. Pin 4 was labelled DNC to start with, but it's always been a 5V pin, just an undocumented one.

Answer (score 1):

you ought to check the traces on the board, if there are no visible connections (PCB tracks) between pins 2 and 4, then something is not right and you'd better check your soldering. RasPi manual clearly says "do not connect anything to DNC pins".